# How to adjust arrow according to circle size?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I created a network graph with d3js. I have circle's of different radius. Each line between circle's have an arrow pointing to its source. How to properly adjust the arrow mark according to the circle radius?

Here is the link of that code in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2NJ25/10/

This is how I append arrow to the line

```
svg.append("defs").append("marker")
        .attr("id", "arrow")
        .attr("refX", 10)
        .attr("refY", 2.2)
        .attr("markerWidth", 10)
        .attr("markerHeight", 10)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M0,0 V4 L5,2 Z10");
```

Comment: You would need to create a new `marker` element for each circle size with the appropriate attributes (i.e. `refX` and `refY`) and then reference that from the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the link. That'll adjust the size of arrow attached to it.

```
var links = svg.append("g").selectAll("line.link")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width", function(d) {
        return (d.target.cRadius) / 5; })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

I notice there's an error with your marker path. Here's the one I use:

```
svg.append("defs").append("marker")
    .attr("id", "arrow")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 21)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("markerWidth", 5)
    .attr("markerHeight", 5)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
.append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

Complete code is here:

http://vida.io/documents/4FSGQ6Pn6dsEHuYaM